# Removing border from last column

Tags: tables

I have a simple table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        X & Y & Z \\ \hline
        &   &   \\ \hline 
        &   &   \\ \hline
        &   &   \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to remove the border from all cells in the last column `Z`.

Is this possible by any chance?

Comment: Use `\cline{1-2}` instead of `\hline` and use `{|c|c|c}` in the column specification of your `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the last vertical line from the `tabular` column specification, and use `\cline`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    X & Y & Z \\ \hline
    1 &   &   \\ \hline 
    & 2  &   \\ \hline
    &   & 3  \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c}
    \cline{1-2}
    X & Y & Z \\ \cline{1-2}
    1 &   &   \\ \cline{1-2} 
    & 2  &   \\ \cline{1-2}
    &   & 3  \\ 
    \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```